# Работа с директориями в java

Tags: java, android, файлы

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: пытаюсь программно работать с каталогом, но сталкиваюсь с тем, что студия на проверке существования этой директории говорит, что ее нету. Хотя она есть, смотри фото. Директория создана как "Directory" да и с "Android Resource Directory" не работает. Пересмотрел кучу источников по работе с директориями и файлами, делаю как там и все равно не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что выводит `System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath())`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Выводит: "../res/icons"

Comment: Вы показали вывод get**Absolute**Path()?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, точнее:  I/System.out: /../res/icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR:**
Вы пытаетесь работать с файлами проекта как с файлами ОС. В ОС искомых файлов по указанным путям не существует.

---

Стандартные средства `Java` для работы с файлами работают в рамках ОС на которой исполняется код вашей программы. В ней ваше приложение, в виде APK файла, должно лежать в папке `data/app/your.package.name`. Именно в этот APK файл будут упакованы все файлы вашего проекта, включая картинки, строки, стили, код etc. Как они там будут размещены - неизвестно, но точно ясно что они не будут являться файлами в ОС, они будут внутренними ресурсами APK файла.

Т.е. вы не можете никак средствами `Java` для работы с файловой системой получить доступ к этим файлам. Вместо этого вам надо использовать средства `AndroidSDK` для доступа к этим файлам.

Например, процесс записи иконки из `res/drawable` в файл будет выглядеть [так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10174399/3212712):

1. Получаем `Drawable` по ID иконки.
2. Конвертируем `Drawable` в `Bitmap`
3. Пишем `Bitmap` в файл.